# How to delete a dictionary entry temporarily on Python after it has been outputted randomnly?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary containing the different cards in a pack of cards for a game of blackjack that I am trying to code. However, after a random card has been outputted, I want to remove it from the dictionary so that, for example, a player does not receive two Jack of Hearts in one round. However, I do not want to remove it permanently as I want it to be back when there is a new round. Here is roughly what I am trying to code (note that the dictionary in my code has all the cards).

```
#Create keys and values for cards
import random
dictCards = {'2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4}

#Distribute cards
print(random.choice(list(dictCards.keys())))
del dictCards(random.choice(list(dictCards.keys())))
print(random.choice(list(dictCards.keys())))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if possible could it be in relatively simple terms as I am new to python. Please feel free to ask if you want me to clear anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list and remove, especially as you are creating a list each time you call `list(dictCards.keys())`:

```
import random
dictCards = {'2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4}

cards = list(dictCards)
print(cards)
choice = random.choice(cards)
cards.remove(choice)
print(choice)
print(cards)

['4 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '2 of Hearts']
4 of Hearts
['3 of Hearts', '2 of Hearts']
```

If you are picking multiple cards you may need a try/except:

```
for _ in range(5):
    try:
        choice = random.choice(cards)
        cards.remove(choice)
        print(choice)
    except IndexError:
        print("Sorry no more cards")
        break
print(cards)

In [14]: paste
dictCards = {'2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4}
cards = list(dictCards)
for _ in range(5):
    try:
        choice = random.choice(cards)
        cards.remove(choice)
        print(choice)
    except IndexError:
        print("Sorry no more cards")
        break
print(cards)

## -- End pasted text --
4 of Hearts
3 of Hearts
2 of Hearts
Sorry no more cards
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of the dictionary (using dictCards.copy()) to hold the cards that haven't been used in the current round, and remove the used cards from that copy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the removed card to some other dictionary say `removed` so you can use back these cards later.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> dictCards = {'2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4}
>>> removed = {}
>>> while dictCards:
...    key = random.choice(list(dictCards.keys()))
...    print(key)
...    removed[key]=dictCards[key]
...    del dictCards[key]
... 
4 of Hearts
2 of Hearts
3 of Hearts
>>> dictCards
{}
>>> removed
{'2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4}
```

You can now assign `removed` back to `dictCards`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `set`s. The dict would stay the same over the whole game an serves as a look-up table for the card values. The variable `stack` holds the cards for one round.

```
import random
dictCards = {'2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4}

# at the beginning of the round you create the card stack
stack = set(dictCards.keys()) 
# then you choose a single card (hence the 1) from the stack
chosenCard = random.sample(stack, 1)[0]
# this card has to be removed from the stack
stack.remove(chosenCard) # stack.discard(chosenCard) is also possible
print("stack:", stack)
print("chosen card:", chosenCard, "with value", dictCards[chosenCard])
```

Output

```
stack: {'3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts'}
chosen card: 2 of Hearts with value 2
```

Comment: Why would you use a set?

Comment: There is the stack of cards and the order of the cards does not matter, because with every turn you choose a random card of the stack. You just want to know, whether a arbitrary card is still in the stack or it is not. These are attributes of an unordered container and this is a set.
Thinking more about it, "stack" is a bad name for a set, because a card stack is ordered, normally. A better approach may be `stack = random.sample(dictCards.keys(), length(dictCards))` and `chosenCard = stack.pop()`. So you do not need the `stack.remove(...)` anymore...

Comment: you would only use a set if you were checking if a value was in something or to remove duplicates, also random.sample for a single value is not a good idea that is exactly what choice is for.